# (react) How to select css pseudo element with useRef in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a piece of css code like this:

```
.nav__icon-wrapper {
/... some code .../
}

.nav__icon-wrapper::after {
    content: '5';
/... some code .../
}
```

I want to change the `content` attribute of the pseudo element `::after` dynamically using `useRef` in react component, but I have no idea how to select pseudo element with `useRef`, I have only tried using `ref.current.style` to select normal css code. Anybody has an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Are you sure that you do the right things? Maybe much easier create another `span` or `div` and change its content dynamically? In my career I've never seen case like this

Comment: Got it, thanks for your idea, it was indeed much more easier.